# css:image in border

Tags: html, css

I want  the border will show an image so for that I used this css which I got from [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) site

```
 border-bottom-image: url('images/header-img.png') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch;
```

But it not worked. I used firebug to see the css but the border-bottom-image is not showing as a part of css in firebug. So can someone please tell me how to use image in border

Comment: border-image currently works in Safari and Firefox 3.1 (Alpha).

are you using one of those two browsers?

Comment: actually a few more...Opera and Chrome as well. Can't link in comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

border-bottom-image is not supported by browsers yet. It's a proposal only.

Edit: 10 months later.

If you also include this helper: http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-image for IE, then support for this if now good enough that it can be used.

Comment: Not in pure css, but see http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jbi for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the image path is correct.  Right now you have a relative url.  You may need to use an absolute path such as `/images/header-img.png`  Notice the leading slash.

You may also need to browser specific declarations:

```
#header  { -moz-border-bottom-image: url('images/header-img.png') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch; } /* firefox */
           -webkit-border-bottom-image: url('images/header-img.png') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch; /* chrome & safari */
           -o-borderbottom-image: url('images/header-img.png') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch; /* Opera */ }
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-image